# UIButton в две строки

Tags: xcode, uibutton

Хочу сделать в UIButton две строки. В общем-то у меня это получается. Но у меня случай, когда вторая строка длиннее первой. И надо их выровнять по центру. Это возможно? Вариант с пробелами не очень нравится.

Answer (score -1):

в .h файле

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
```

в .m файле

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[self.button1.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.button1 setTitle:@"text\nlong text" forState:0];
}
```

Comment: а почему аутлет в .h?

Comment: а почему бы и нет?

Comment: потому что инкапсуляция

Comment: сомневаюсь что для objective-c уместно употребление этого слова)

Comment: извольте объясниться